# Getting List.Sort() result is wrong

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting

The issue is that when I sort a list of Points with X and Y All but one of the points that has the same X as 4 other points but has the smallest Y gets put at the index location second from last in the list. At first I was just making sure that sort performed more then one irritation since all points only moved one spot and nothing more then that from where they started in the list.  This is my compare to method that is used to sort the list:

```
Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Point) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of Point).CompareTo
        Dim xCompare As Integer = Me.X.CompareTo(other.X)
        If xCompare = 0 Then
            Return Me.Y.CompareTo(other.Y)
        End If
        Return xCompare
    End Function
```

Items after being sorted

> 1: 18.750,144.500
>
> 2: 19.440,88.642
>
> 3: 21.750,112.925
>
> 4: 21.750,134.375
>
> 5: 21.750,89.646
>
> 6: 21.750,144.500

As you can see the item at 5 should be moved to the third item in the list.

Comment: by `if anything has changed` do you mean the contents of the list changed (as in something added or inserted)?

Comment: Calling `Sort()` once fully sorts the list. I don't understand why you'd want to repeatedly call `Sort()`.

Comment: you could make sure that they are sorted by using a `SortedList`

Comment: @itsme86 I have a issue where one item in the list that should be in the front but it is second from the last after performing the sort. So does Sort perform one instance of a bubble sort? It seemed like it did.

Comment: @Kyle what exactly are you sorting? perhaps your comparison function is broken/not stable.

Comment: No, Sort does not perform one iteration of a bubble sort. It fully sorts the list. What is in your list, and does it properly implement IComparable?

Comment: @Kyle Nope, it sorts the entire list. Maybe the sort isn't behaving the way you expect though. Is it a string of numbers sorting as a string instead of numerically?

Comment: It is sorting a list of points with X and Y

Comment: Calling just sort() might not be perfect for that

Comment: how do you want to sort it? by x or by y? asc or desc?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I added the code that does the sorting using compare to

Comment: You cant abort the sort earlier just because this element doesnt move if *thats* what you are asking.  Comparing this element tells you nothing about element+1 or element+N

Comment: @Plutonix No that was not what I was asking. I was asking since I wasn't 100% if the Sort just performed one irritation or kept going till it was 100% sorted.

Comment: @DanielA.White I posted my sort compare to. Do you notice anything that would seem broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing logically wrong with your comparison algorithm.  It's plausible that your actual floating-point values are *very slightly different*, resulting in the order you observe.  I would suggest adding a tolerance for "equal" values when comparing, possibly by rounding to, say, 3 decimals:

```
Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Point) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of Point).CompareTo
        Dim xCompare As Integer = Math.Round(Me.X,3).CompareTo(Math.Round(other.X,3))
        If xCompare = 0 Then
            Return Math.Round(Me.Y,3).CompareTo(Math.Round(other.Y,3))
        End If
        Return xCompare
    End Function
```

The choice of 3 decimals is arbitrary; I only chose it because that's what you display.  Using more decimals would preserve more "true" differences but would increase the chance of false positives due to floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you for posting something actually revolves around my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you don't understand how Sort works.

By your code example, it appears you think you have to call sort multiple times to get all elements of a List sorted. But this isn't true.

Calling it once sorts all elements in the List.  If, after sorting, you add an element or change the value of an element, then you might need to call sort again.  So, it is pointless to tell if the sort process is occurring--your code won't continue until all elements are in correct order.

The built-in Sort function is also optimized to be as quick as possible.  If you call it and everything is already in the correct order, very little processing power will occur--it will simply confirm that everything is in order.